# Invalid directory for database creation on dynamodb start

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, amazon-dynamodb-local

I am getting `Invalid directory for database creation.` when I start serverless-dynamodb-local.

Below is my local configuration

```
dynamodb:
    stages:
      - test
    start:
      port: 8000
      sharedDb: true
      dbPath: dynamodb-local
```

Is there anything I am missing?